# Download artifact(in yaml pipeline) from pipeline in different organization

Tags: azure, azure-artifacts

How to download artifact from pipeline in different organization ?
I tried to use this task by creating service connect to external Organization.
task used][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mG2q.png)

But it doesn't work , my yaml pipeline throws error.[pipeline log summary of above mentioned task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl1E5.png) (I know this possible , just looking for a quick solution. FYI , I was able to do this in a classic release pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this task in yaml pipeline and it works well. The warning in the log does not affect the final execution of the task. Did your task execute successfully?  Does the log message show the download file information as shown in the figure below?

[image]